# How to build a WiFi repeater using the Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, wifi

I want to repeat the WiFi I'm using and send it to my phone via WiFi , without ethernet cables (like the [alfa r36](http://www.alfa.com.tw/products_show.php?pc=51&ps=11)) [image: Alfa R36 WiFi Repeater diagram]

I want to use the Raspberry Pi as the R36: No Ethernet cable, just two USB WiFi adapters; one to receive the signal and the other one to send it on. How do I enable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the RPi as a bridge, including between 2 USB wifi interfaces, wired interfaces or any combination. Be aware, though, that most of the USB "nano" type wifi adapters don't perform at what you might expect from the packaging. I tested Edimax, TP-Link and generic adapters on a desktop PC, and none would connect at any higher than 54 Mbps in the same room as my wifi router, including the "n" compatible versions. The generic was limited to 35 or so Mbps.

The RPi 2B itself can bridge traffic at over 100 Mbps without a problem, despite the limitations of the USB-Ethernet controller. The cheap wifi adapters are the limitation. Using 2 wifi adapters, I couldn't get more than 10 Mbps of throughput. If this is sufficient, or if you're willing to buy adapters that cost more than the RPi itself, along with the appropriate antennas, you might be able to do this satisfactorily.

I am not sure if the device shown in the window on your drawing is just an external antenna, or a wireless-wired bridge. In any case, I'd expect to have to use some external antennas to get it to work unless that outdoor antenna is located very near to your house. So while you might be able to get a RPi to work, there may be special-purpose devices out there that will cost less in the end to get working.

Comment: it cost 160$ the wifi usb alfa antena with the  exterior 24dbi antena and the alfa repeater , i use the alfa to catch the signal and the r36 resend the signal in my house , and so you are telling that doint the same thing is more expensive :O :/ , thanks i dont knew im new here , thansk for the help

Comment: I don't *know* that it's more expensive, but it's easy to spend $160 on antennas (esp. 24dBi) and the repeater. The R36 looks to be the easiest piece to replace with the RPi, but the other costs remain. Also, in that drawing, the R36 looks like it's a wired-wireless repeater. The RPi might work well enough in that configuration, just not with 2 cheap USB wifi adapters.

Comment: oki thanks for the help ! :) and yes the r36 have a usb cable to the wifi antena